# Lambda functions back to anonymous classes

Tags: java, android, lambda, java-8, java-7

I am backporting an android application made for Android 9 back to work with android 5.1 and there are a lot of problems,
among them there is the fact that Java 8 is not supported.
Lambdas and method referencing were heavily used.
When i encounter a lambda or method reference, i get the java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError.

To be precise,

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   com.company.appname.data.entities.-$$Lambda$Event$a39TwGpGAlTjSZ6A7VoEq_FJFA0

pointing to the line of the class containing the lambda.
Is there a way to backport them without rewriting them all and if there is a way to convert them automatically.

I have tried Retrolambda, imported it but it still gets the same error.

Comment: try to Clean and ReBuild the project

Comment: Might be a bit extreme but perhaps you could use Kotlin, it supports Java 6, and it might be easier to port the lambdas.

Comment: Example code? Lambdas and method references alone are no problem for API level 22. Both, Android Studio 3.x and retrolambda can handle them well. (That said, nowadays you really should use Android Studio for that task)

Comment: Wait so lambda fuctions are included without retrolambda?
Which means i should remove it right? are filters also included for use with them?

The sample code itself is not useful as it happens on all places lambda functions are used.

Comment: Yes, remove it. What do you mean by `filters`? It's only the Java 8 `language` constructs that are supported for older Android versions. If your code uses Java 8 `API` (e.g. streams) you are on your own.

Comment: Ok thanks, but to get back to the Java 8 API,
if i were to convert it to Kotlin, would i then be able to use the kotlin alternatives from Java 8?